# Pivot chord but different scale. ( Ex. G; C and C; C ) is it possible to use them as a pivot chord to one another?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

Even though the scales are different,

G; C - lydian , C; C - Ionian .

Is it possible to use this as a pivot chord to modulate to one another ?

If it is possible, how ?

Comment: 'Even though the scales are different'. How. Doesn't G contain the same notes as C Lydian? It's the 'home' that is different.

Comment: @Tim What I'm asking is,
from G key, the C chord ( IV ) scale is Lydian.and from C Key, the C chord ( I ) scale is Ionian.
even though they are the same C chord, the scale are different from each other.

So is it possible to see this two as a pivot chord connection between G key and C key,and see the G key's C ( IV ) chord as C key's tonic ( I ) and allowed to proceed ?

and is this how pivot chord work ?

Comment: Plenty of information about this on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation_(music)#Common-chord_modulation

Answer (score 1):

Common chord modulation uses chords common to both keys. That just makes life simple, and sounds natural. Sometimes called diatonic pivot chord modulation. Thus, let's say we go from key G to key C.

The chords common to both G and C are Am and Em, as well as the obvious G and C. So using any as a pivot chord will facilitate modulation. The other chords available in those keys - Dm, F, Bm, D, Bo and F#o usually won't work as pivot keys. Except D, when moving *from* C *to* G, where it's going to work, as it's the dominant of the new key - why wouldn't it work - *but*, it's not part of the C inventory (although D7 contains C), so it'll sound quite abrupt - not what pivot chords are about.

So, basically, both G and C are pivot chords of each other.

Comment: Tim, in fact you *need* the D7 for a convincing modulation to G. The C is the pivot chord and the D7 confirms its purpose. Otherwise, there is no modulation, just a chord change or modal transition at best.